# Skip first node and Copy rest of the nodes using XSLT 3.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I will need to skip first `Worker` node and copy rest of the nodes using XSLT 3.0

My source XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <Employee>Emp</Employee>
        <ID>Identifier</ID>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Employee>12344</Employee>
        <ID>1245599</ID>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Employee>25644</Employee>
        <ID>7823565</ID>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

and desired output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Workers>
   <Worker>
      <Employee>12344</Employee>
      <ID>1245599</ID>
   </Worker>
   <Worker>
      <Employee>25644</Employee>
      <ID>7823565</ID>
   </Worker>
</Workers>
```

and XSLT that i have is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="Worker[position() = 1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Above XSLT produces the output that I was expecting but I'm looking to see if there is a better way to skip the first node without using `postion()`as I'm not sure how efficient my current code is to process large files( approximately 800 MB)

I had to use following to remove white spaces from my result XML

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Can anyone check my code and provide any suggestion to improvise my code please?

===============

With Michael Kay's suggestion, my code looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 
    
  <!-- <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> -->
 
 <!-- Removed above Identity Transformation -->

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="Workers">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(Worker)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "I'm not sure how efficient my current code is": do you run out of memory with your XSLT processor? Which one do you use? Can you or do you want to use Saxon EE and streaming do work around memory limitations? In that case using an accumulator would help to make the code streamable.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen - I'm not facing any issue at the moment because of small data sets (less than 100MB) but i expect at some point the size of data would go up to 800MB. That's what my concern is. I'm currently using Saxon EE 9.7.0.12. Would it be possible for you to show me how to make this streamable using an accumulator please?

Comment: Accumulators are explained in the XSLT 3 specification. However, 9.7 is the last release before XSLT 3 became a W3C standard so I would suggest to move to a current release or look into the Saxon 9.7 documentation if you can't do that.

Comment: Note that streaming has to be enabled with e.g. `<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-mode="shallow-copy"/>` and that the spelled out version of the identity transformation you have used in your sample processing `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />` would not get by a streamability analysis, at least if done with an XSLT 3 processor following the final XSLT 3 spec.

Comment: Thank you sir, I totally missed it. Now edited with `<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it

```
<xsl:template match="Worker[1]"/>
```

for readability, but it's all the same.

Match patterns with positional predicates can perform badly, so you're right to be cautious, but a simple one like this should be OK. In fact the main adverse consequence is probably that Saxon will allocate preceding-sibling pointers in the TinyTree, so that it can compute the node's sibling position.

Saxon effectively implements it as

```
<xsl:template match="Worker[not(preceding-sibling::Worker)]"/>
```

and you might prefer to write it that way. However, neither form is streamable.

To make it streamable, you could drop the unwanted nodes by not selecting them:

```
<xsl:template match="Workers">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(Worker)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

which might also be fractionally faster in the non-streaming case; and it saves memory because preceding-sibling pointers aren't needed.

Comment: Thank you sir, I have edited my original question with the suggestion you provided which produces the expected result.